# Angular Upgradation Version 8 To Version 9. Purpose Of --create-commits Option

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, angular-upgrade

Alright. So, I'm trying to Upgrade an Angular App from Version 8 to Version 9 (8.2 To 9.0). It is mentioned in the [Angular Update Website "During the Update" section](https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=8.2-9.0) like We can optionally pass **--create-commits (or -C)** flag. What does it do actually?? Is it something like **update** process automatically take care of each changes & Commits?? Can Someone explain me in Detail?? Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

As i remember each run of `ng update` require your git tree to be clean to run, that is why you can pass the `--create-commits` flag, so you don't have to commit your changes manually every time you run `ng update`.